Firebase configurar firestore database
como puedo configurar en mi proyecto angular que esta en un monorepo la segunda database ya que siempre se conecta la por defecto


Hola. Mira los ejemplos de código en este hilo de Github o bien esta pregunta.

Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.
